# En consulta SQL controlar si un campo fechaA es igual a "01/01/1900" y si es asi que devuelva el valor de otro campo fechaB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Tengo una consulta SQL muy larga en uno de sus parrafos necesito controlar si un campo fechaA es igual a "01/01/1900" y si es asi que devuelva el valor de otro campo fechaB.

Como comentaba la consulta es muy muy larga con otros CASE, argumentos, etc.. de por medio. Entonces entre el código hay un trozo con T1.FechaA, T2.Importe... y yo he agregado T1.FechaA ( CASE WHEN T1.FechaA = '1900-01-01' THEN T1.FechaB END), T2.Importe... pero me da error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aquí tendrías un ejemplo con `CASE`:
Donde te mostrará siempre lo que haya en el campo fechaA salvo que este sea igual a la fecha '01/01/1900' que en ese caso te mostrará el valor de fechaB

```
select campo1, campo2, campo3, 
  case when fechaA = '01/01/1900'
  then fechaB
  else fechaA
  end AliasQueLeQuierasDar
from tabla1
where campo1 = condicion1
```

Lo del Alias, no estoy seguro de que en SQLServer funcione, ahora mismo lo he podido probar en una base de datos Oracle, pero las sentencias CASE son iguales en ambos lenguajes si no me equivoco.

Comment: Voy a editar el enunciado, para que se entienda mejor lo que pido. El caso es que necesito mediante un IF o algo parecido donde haya un campo1 de tipo fecha sustituirlo en tiempo de ejecución por campo2 de tipo fecha

Comment: Con lo que me pusistes ya encontré la solución solo tuve que hacer la parte del case la puse asi: CASE WHEN t1.fechaA = '1900-01-01' THEN t1.fechaB END AS fecha

Comment: No puse solamente la parte del `CASE` porque sino la consulta quedaba muy escueta y si no se entiende de SQL viendo solo eso no es facil verlo. Por eso es que están el resto de los campos.

Comment: Ok , gracias por la respuesta !

Answer (score 2):

Así?

```
SELECT fechaB
FROM tabla
WHERE fechaA = '1900-01-01'
```

O con un `CASE` si quieres mantener todos los valores de la consulta

```
SELECT
   CASE 
       WHEN fechaA = '1900-01-01' THEN fechaB
       ELSE fechaA
   END AS fechaX
FROM tabla
```

Comment: Como comentaba la consulta es muy muy larga con otros CASE, argumentos, etc.. de por medio. Entonces entre el código hay  un trozo con T1.FechaA, T2.Importe... y yo he agregado  T1.FechaA ( CASE WHEN T1.FechaA = '1900-01-01' THEN T1.FechaB END), T2.Importe... pero me da error

Comment: ya encontré la solución gracias.